# Password hash flow - especially reset password

Tags: php, password-encryption

I'm updating the way I store passwords on my sites and want to share my flow thoughts to make sure I do it right:

Firstly a user will choose a password which I'll hash:

```
function generateHash($password) {
    if (defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) {
        $salt = '$2y$11$' . substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 22);
        return crypt($password, $salt);
    }
}

$passToStore = generateHash($userPassword);
```

Then I am going to store this in a table purely for password with the auto generated `userId` from users table as the key:

```
userId INT
hashedPassword VARCHAR(22)
forgottenHash VARCHAR(36)
```

When a user then returns and tries to login, I will extract the password in a join select query from the email (username) they enter. Then check that matches what they enter:

```
function verify($passwordEntered, $hashedPasswordStored) {
    return crypt($passwordEntered, $hashedPasswordStored) == $hashedPassword;
}
```

If a user forgets their password, they enter their email address and I will generate a random hash and make it unique adding `strtotime` current time/date (to go into `forgottenHash`) and then send a link for them to click with their email and that random hash as the key and in the URL.

If they click the link and the hash matches the user with that email address I'll delete the hashed password stored and let them create a new one. I'm concerned with the thought process for resetting password but it seems right to me. But then I'm not a hacker.

Is this a good way to manage passwords or is there a better way?

Comment: `rand()` is not suitable for cryptographic randomness.

Comment: Why don't you use password_hash() and password_verify()?

Comment: Rather than using hash() or crypt() directly, I would recommend using PHP 5.5's [built-in password functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.password.php), which are available as a one-file download for older versions.

Comment: @IMSoP Didn't even know that existed. Saves a lot of work, many thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also see Openwall's [PHP password hashing framework](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) (PHPass). Its portable and hardened against a number of common attacks on user passwords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already mentioned in the comments there are functions to do the hashing. They will also generate a safe salt for you:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

The forgotten password function should be done a little bit different as you proposed. While the password-hash normally is stored in the "users" table, you should create a separate table for password resets. When requested by the user you generate a **random** token which is not derrived from other user data and store a **hash** of it in the new table, together with the user-id. The token itself you send to the user. If the user clicks the link with the token, then you can calculate the hash of this token again and search for it in the table, if it matches you allow the user to change the password.

Comment: This is the way to go. If you are using PHP < 5.5, you can use [this compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) that implements the same functions for PHP versions < 5.5.

Comment: What if someone tries guess the token? `https://example.com/reset-password/some-token-here`. So someone is trying to open the page with this token and it exists in the `user_reset_token` table. `password_verify` will see this as true when it compares the guessed token and the token from the database, right?

Comment: @TomaTomov - Tokens are long random combinations (20+ characters a-z A-Z 0-9). There are so many possible combinations that it is impossible to guess them. If you could test 1Giga combinations per sec for a 24 character token with 1E43 combinations, you can still expect about 100'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000 years to find a given token (many times the age of the univers).